# How to use flutter to send SMS content to specific gmail automatically

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-functional-widget

i want to make app to capture SMS content and send it directly to specific gmail without any share button

i want to know how to implement this app or the function

Comment: you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for incoming SMS and then write a background service to capture the same, to send mail using any email service like SendGrid, For implementing bg service in flutter use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager)